# How can I display total population and density in dashboardheader in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to create this shiny dashboard, where I want to display live total US population and density in the dashboardHeader in R Shiny. This will act like a counter. I have other details to display in the body part. So please let me know how I could achieve this.

table: Population (column names: date, population, density)

Shiny dashboardHeader: Contains:

**US Population** .............................................................**Population:** xxxxxxx **Density:** yyyyy

Population and Density should appear in the right corner of the header area

Comment: Please provide sample code and what you have tried so far

Comment: @Kris4u : Perhaps you are seeing the results (or no results) as a result of an insufficiently specific question. There is no data or code, so people cannot tell where you are getting stuck. SO respondents generally frown upon requests to "just give me the code" to do Z with X, especially so when they cannot really tell what X might really be.